# Twilio: Incoming sms: Can i verify the number it was sent from?

Tags: php, twilio

Example:

> Dave is a member of my site, I know his phone number is 07123 456789.
>
> I'd like for him to be able to sms status updates to my server from
>   his phone (through twilio).

Is there any way I can verify that his text came from 07123 456789?

thanks!

Comment: Yes. The api can see the source number. What is your real question?

Comment: Thanks Antony. How trustworthy is this info? Is it easy for someone to spoof?

Comment: An SMS is sent from the phone of userA to Twilio number B. Twilio captures the source of the message and all other details. If the question is can twilio know when the 'from' number is spoofed? Probably not, or it wouldn't show that number. If the question is : can someone spoof the number an SMS is sent from? Probably so, but you aren't likely to get anything done worrying about it, let alone thinking you can get around it, assuming it can be done. I know that the 'From' number on a call can be spoofed, so it stands to reason anything can. Will double check.

Comment: http://www.smsspoofing.com/  - based on this site and not digging further, it can be done at the phone level but can be validated at the carrier level, which means that it requires a user who knows how to spoof from their phone who is sending over a network that doesn't bother to reverse-lookup the source along the way, and in the US, this is apparently never been pulled off successfully.

Comment: Thanks Antony, I'll try a few of those spoofing services as a potential 'customer' and see what can easily be done here in the uk...

Comment: Hey, Twilio employee here. Phone number verification is often one of the things people build with Twilio. You can send the number a text message asking them to type in a generated code into the website. This can help make sure the number is genuinely connected to the person who claims to own it. Have you thought about providing a similar service?

Comment: @phalt - I think the op is worried about per message verification. Seems like that would be overkill with a verify code every time. Especially if SMS number hijacking is rare to impossible. But I defer to the experts, so let me know.